# Sending packets using Craftbukkits API not working

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I have been trying to send JSON Raw messages to players using a lot of different methods and none of them seem to work. One thing I have tried is to do this:

```
        String json = "{text:\"Test!\",hoverEvent:{action:show_text,value:\"test\"}}";
        PacketPlayOutChat packet = new PacketPlayOutChat(ChatSerializer.a(json), true);
        ((CraftPlayer) player).getHandle().playerConnection.sendPacket(packet);
```

Now when eclipse validates the code, no errors appear and it's only when the server runs this code, it gives me this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/minecraft/server/v1_7_R3/Packet
        at bukkit.pangea.terms.Main.registerCommands(Main.java:31) ~[?:?]
        at bukkit.pangea.terms.Main.onEnable(Main.java:21) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:321) ~[c
raftbukkit.jar:git-Spigot-952179b-e87122e]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader
.java:335) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Spigot-952179b-e87122e]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManage
r.java:405) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Spigot-952179b-e87122e]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.jav
a:356) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Spigot-952179b-e87122e]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.
java:316) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Spigot-952179b-e87122e]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:74
6) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Spigot-952179b-e87122e]
        at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:534) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Spigot
-952179b-e87122e]
        at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:
25) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Spigot-952179b-e87122e]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:14
1) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Spigot-952179b-e87122e]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServe
r.java:646) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Spigot-952179b-e87122e]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(Craf
tServer.java:632) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Spigot-952179b-e87122e]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.DedicatedServer.aM(DedicatedServer.java:
353) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Spigot-952179b-e87122e]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.DedicatedServer.z(DedicatedServer.java:3
17) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Spigot-952179b-e87122e]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.y(MinecraftServer.java:6
23) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Spigot-952179b-e87122e]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java
:526) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Spigot-952179b-e87122e]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_71]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.Packet

        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.
java:91) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Spigot-952179b-e87122e]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.
java:86) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Spigot-952179b-e87122e]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_71]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_71]
        ... 18 more
```

A lot of the other things that I have tried also gives me a similar error. If anyone could help me with this problem it would be very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method works perfectly fine in my version of spigot/craftbukkit, although it seems that I am using a newer version (1.8.3), in which the constructor for the PacketPlayOutChat takes a byte as a second argument instead of a boolean. This byte (values 1 or 2) determines whether the chat message is sent normally or is displayed above the action bar. I would update your craftbukkit/spigot jar to the newest version using [BuildTools](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/buildtools/).

Answer (score 0):

Well it could be, that you use another spigot/bukkit jar on your server, than you work with. Use exactly the same. Otherwise it couldn't find the main class of the server Packet version.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/minecraft/server/v1_7_R3/Packet
```

Here it says, that it can't find the class. Which Spigot/Bukkit version are you using on your server? And which are you using to developing?

Comment: I'm using a Craftbukkit version that has been mixed with spigot. I cant remember the version exactly but its 1.8. I have also referenced the same .jar file in my project as I am using for the server.

Comment: Well is it the spigot, that allows 1.8 and 1.7 clients?

Comment: No, it only allows 1.8 clients

Comment: I could send you the Craftbukkit.jar that I use if it would help?

Comment: Which version of ProtocolLib are you using?

Comment: Well so it could be, that you should use a inofficial build. Here you and find these builds: http://ci.shadowvolt.com/job/ProtocolLib/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81788/discussion-between-jordan-and-nicola-uetz).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a later version of Spigot in your build path for your project. If you cannot build it as described by the answer above, then you can depend on the jar used by the server instead.